# Can't display images in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, osx, display, image-mode, inline-image

I am on MacOS High Sierra, iterm2; I cannot find how to display images in org-mode. My term supports image display as `imgcat` works well within my shell. When I try to open the image link in emacs it returns `Display not supported` then the verbose is gibberish. I don't want use GUI emacs. I have tried to install Spacemacs but it does not solve the issue. I have tried to turn on `iimage`, `imageMagick` without luck. Any idea?

Comment: It is likely that emacs does not support iterm2's proprietary image format.

Comment: Emacs is supposed to support jpg/png format, isn't it?

Comment: Emacs does support jpg/png. It knows how to read those files and turn them into pixel data. And it knows how to draw them to a GUI. What you're asking for is for Emacs to know how to draw them to iterm2's proprietary format, and I don't think Emacs has code for that. Emacs has code for terminals, but not specifically for iterm2's features.

Comment: You are right. No way to display an image in emacs on os x, outside emacs GUI, which is actually good!

Comment: Would opening an issue at iTerm2 for this  help?